# how to get an object after saving it to the database

Tags: django

i am trying to use django allauth to send confirmation emails on sign-up,after successfully sending the email i need top have a way to identify if the user has confirmed his email,dajngo allauth provides somthing for that

```
from allauth.account.signals import email_confirmed

@receiver(email_confirmed)
def email_confirmed_(request, email_address, **kwargs):
    user = email_address.user
    user.email_verified = True
    user.save()
```

what i can't figure out how to do is access the user.email_verified that i saved

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def current_user(request,user):
    current_user = request.user
        return Response({
            'id': current_user.id,
            'verified': user.email_verified #???????
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you doing something like this to access a model instance:
(considering the name of your model is User) - `User.objects.filter(id=current_user.id)`
you can define a variable like this:
`user_obj = User.objects.filter(id=current_user.id)`
and than you accessing it's field as:
`user_obj.email_verified`

is this what you need?